# Geometric interpreation of triple product ∇ · (∇ × a)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

In vector calculus I understand how div is kind of a measure of how much a point acts as a source or sink of the field lines or a measure of the flux through a closed shape at a point in a sense. The curl is a measure of how much rotation the surrounding vector field causes at a point (Please correct if this is wrong).

Just wanted to know if there was also a geometric meaning for the triple product   ∇ · (∇ × a). I cant seem to reason it out.

Comment: You know that this quantity is always zero, right?

Comment: Yes, which is all the more reason why I wanted to know its geoemetric meaning, considering the other two have ones. Why combining them in this way results in 0.